# How to add an inner (nested) class to a library class?

Tags: vb.net, inner-classes, nested-class

I'm trying to add a custom event generator inner class to reuse through several `Form`s.  I was at first just going to put it the relevant code inside a `#Region` and copy-paste it into the code, but I realized a better way would maybe be to do it in a nested class.  So I want to basically do

```
Partial Class Form
     Public Class VerifyGenerator
     ...
     End Class
End Class

Public Class MyForm
    Inherits Form

    Public Class MyVerifyGenerator
    ...
    End Class
End Class
```

If there's a better / more logical solution to this, I'm all ears.  In the `Form` there's logic to find all the `TextBox`es with `VerifyHandler`s and subscribe them to the event when the `Form` generates it, custom logic to disable (most) other `Control`s

Answer (score 0):

Could you just create a base class that exposed that functionality and inherit from it?

```
Public MustInherit Class VerifyerForm
  Inherits Form

  '  your stuff here

End Class


Public Class MyForm
  Inherits VerifyerForm

End Class
```

Comment: I would love to if multiple inheritance were an option, but as it is I've already done this with navigation functionality

Comment: Come to think of it, the obvious answer would be to just have a class with a `Form` set in its constructor, and I could just keep any derived `VerifyGenerator`s in the same file as where it's used.  The only downside would be it would be visible in code browser etc.

Comment: Have your Verifyer inherit from your navigator, or vice/versa.  Also, the Vertifyer taking a Form in its .ctor seems like a great option.